# how to pass list of object to oracle stored procedure in spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I am going through the advance oracle datatype in spring tutorial ([follow here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html)). I'm facing a problem while persisting data in oracle through stored procedure. In this tutorial object of actor class is persisted using advance data type in oracle.

However, my requirement is to persist list of person class which contain list of address which again contain list of line.

**Example-**

```
class Person{
String name;
int id;
List<Address> address;
}

class Address{
String city;
String state;
List<String> line;
}
```

I tried creating below SQLData and then passing arraytype as input parameter to procedute-

```
Person implements SQLData 
Address implements SQLData 

new SqlParameter("in_person", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "PERSON_ARRAY"));
```

However I'm still not able to persist the data. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Formatted question body